# Is a civil divorce valid?

Tags: nikah

I've gotten married with a woman, but she had civil divorce from her ex-husband.  My question is:  Am I legally her husband and is her divorce valid?

Comment: Please define "civil divorce". If you mean a divorce effected by a court, then its validity would depend upon whether the ex-husband gave the divorce or it was processed unilaterally by the court. In the latter case the validity would depend upon whether it was processed according to Islamic laws and by a Muslim judge. If the husband gave or conceded the divorce it is always valid. If the marriage contract allowed the wife to give the divorce it is valid. If an Islamic judge enforced the divorce it is valid.

Comment: The ex-husband would be the best source that can give you the most correct information.

Answer (score 0):

whatever is meant here by "civil divorce" would be valid as long as the consent of both the parties is there or it is sought on sound grounds. Although under Islamic law the right of divorce is given to the husband only. A Woman can extricate herself from the bond of marriage on sound grounds and through the proper forum. (thereby depriving the husband of the absoluteness of the right of granting divorce).

The question, however, arises as to what made the man ask this question now and not at the time of getting married?

In my opinion, if the woman in question, sought the Divorce (technically Khula) on valid and sound grounds, would be valid, even if not granted at the proper forum for lack of non-availability of the forum. (Allah knows best--I seek His refuge for proferring my earnest opinion).